# C# WPF Array of Buttons, Button Coordinates

Tags: c#, button, wpf-controls

I'm having a matrix of buttons created in the main grid in a window, and also created the event for each one.
I also have an integer matrix that contains some properties of each button(e.g. int a[1,2] is property for button btn[1,2]).
I am planning to create something like a maze on which you can only pass from one button to another by leaping in the knight(from chess) way.I dont know how to find the coordinates of the button pressed so that I may change the position of the current button.

```
 Button[,] btn = new Button[25, 25];
        for (x = 5; x <= n; x++)
        {
            for (y = 5; y <= n; y++)
            {
                btn[x, y] = new Button();
                left += 72;
                btn[x,y].Margin =new Thickness(left,top,0,0);
                btn[x,y].Height = 32;
                btn[x,y].Width = 32;
                btn[x, y].Click += new RoutedEventHandler(btn_Click);

                if (a[x, y] == 2)
                    btn[x,y].Background = Brushes.Red; 
                else
                    btn[x,y].Background = Brushes.Blue;
                main.Children.Add(btn[x, y]);


            }
            left = 0;
            top += 72;
        }

    }
    private void btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

Comment: in btn_Click() you can do this: Button btn = (Button)sender;

Comment: @Dilshod True, but to be safe `Button btn = sender as Button;`, if the sender is no button, `null` will be returned instead of an exception thrown.

Comment: Sure you are right. Or you can check first: if(sender is Button){//then cast it}

Comment: And where will my coordinates be if I do this?

Comment: @bash.d why would you set up another control to trigger `btn_Click`? If that was done, I'd *want* the program to crash so that I can fix it right away!!

Comment: @Default Sorry, but I don't get you right now...

Comment: @bash.d what I mean is, I'd rather get an exception instead of a null value. I'd *want* the program to throw an exception, because "btn_Click" should only handle button clicks. not other controls. If I get an exception, I see that there is an error right away. If I use `as` I don't get an exception.

Comment: @Default okay, personal taste...

Answer (score 0):

I just go a crazy idea... Why not make your own `Button` and call it `MazeButton`, or something?
Derive from `Button` and add some properties, make use of inheritance.

```
public class MazeButton : System.Windows.Controls.Button {
private int left;
private int top;

//rest of implementation

}
```

In that way you can pass the information where the button in your maze resides directly into the button. You can define custom events and anything else you desire.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    private void btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

         Button btn = sender as Buttonl;
         if(btn!=null)
         {
             Point renderedLocation = btn.TranslatePoint(new Point(0, 0), this);
         }
         else
         {
              //you may throw an exception if you want.
         }
    }
```

Comment: You're doing two casts here, first one to check if the sender is a Button and then again when you're casting it to a button. You can use as and check for null, resulting in one cast.

Comment: almost. This wouldn't compile though :) (you forgot the `;` after `as Button1` and `Button1` should probably be `Button`). If the `else` case sole purpose is to throw an exception, you might as well do `Button btn = (Button)sender;` which will throw an exception if sender isn't a `Button` - this is what I would prefer. But others might fancy the `as Button` more.

Comment: I think the person who is using it could fix it. I didn't try to compile it.:)

Answer (score 0):

this is another approch of the problem. I store each button in a List of Tuple instead of a array, then i search wich tuple contains the button with Linq.

This is assuming you are in .NET 4. If not, the class Tuple can be written (you can find it on SO).

```
    private List<Tuple<Button, Int32, Int32>> listButton;
    private void SetButtons()
    {
        // TODO define what is n, left, top

        listButton = new List<Tuple<Button, int, int>>();

        for (int x = 5; x <= n; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 5; y <= n; y++)
            {
                Button btn = new Button();
                left += 72;
                btn.Margin = new Thickness(left, top, 0, 0);
                btn.Height = 32;
                btn.Width = 32;
                btn.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(btn_Click);

                if (a[x, y] == 2)
                    btn.Background = Brushes.Red;
                else
                    btn.Background = Brushes.Blue;

                listButton.Add(new Tuple<Button, int, int>(btn, x, y));

                main.Children.Add(btn);
            }
            left = 0;
            top += 72;
        }
    }

    private void btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Button button = (Button)sender;

        var tuple = listButton.Where(t => t.Item1 == button).FirstOrDefault();

        if (tuple != null)
        {
            Int32 x = tuple.Item2;
            Int32 y = tuple.Item3;

            // Do whay you want this x and y found
        }
   }
```